# How to select one item from list Kotlin Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I was trying to select only one item from list but the probleme that I can select multiple items so how to correct this issue plz
this is my adapter

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PileListeViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val pile = listePiles[position]
        holder.bind(pile)
        val context = holder.binding.root.context
        holder.binding.simpleItemPile.setOnClickListener {
            onItemSelected(pile)
            if (selectedItemPosition != null) {
                selectedItemPosition = holder.adapterPosition
                notifyItemChanged(selectedItemPosition)
            } else {
                selectedItemPosition = holder.adapterPosition
            }
            notifyItemChanged(position)
        }
        if (selectedItemPosition == holder.adapterPosition) {
            holder.binding.simpleItemPile.background = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(
                context,
                R.drawable.background_bleu_statut
            )
        }

    }
```

this is a part of my onViewCreated in fragment

```
listePiles.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { listePile ->
            if (listePile.isNotEmpty() == true) {
                binding.Loading.isVisible = false

                binding.ListepilesRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
                binding.ListepilesRecyclerView.adapter = PileAdapter(listePile,
                    onItemSelected = {
                           pileEcran -> displayButtons(pileEcran)

                        binding.SupprimerImageButton.setOnClickListener{
                            deletePile(pileEcran)
                        }

                        binding.EditerImageButton.setOnClickListener{
                             lifecycleScope.launch{
                                pileEcran.idPile?.let { it1 ->
                                    goToRecapListe(it1)
                                }


                            }
                        }
                    })
```

Comment: Although I don't understand what you or your code is trying to achieve, you are passing the whole list on the `onItemSelected` method. 
So, instead of `onItemSelected(pile)` you should use `onItemSelected(pile[position])`

Comment: No I'm passing a pile which is an item not the list

Answer (score 0):

In this code:

```
if (selectedItemPosition != null) {
    selectedItemPosition = holder.adapterPosition
    notifyItemChanged(selectedItemPosition)
}
```

You are notifying the change of the new position instead of the old position, so you are neglecting it. You need to do something like this:

```
if (selectedItemPosition != null) {
    val previous = selectedItemPosition
    selectedItemPosition = holder.adapterPosition
    notifyItemChanged(previous)
}
```

Also, in this code:

```
    if (selectedItemPosition == holder.adapterPosition) {
        holder.binding.simpleItemPile.background = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(
            context,
            R.drawable.background_bleu_statut
        )
    }
```

you are changing items to show when they are selected, but you are never changing items back to unselected. As these views are recycled, more and more of your views will absorb the selected appearance state and they can never change back. You need to replace it with something like:

```
    val itemBackground = if (selectedItemPosition == holder.adapterPosition) R.drawable.background_bleu_statut else R.drawable.background_your_default_unselected_color
    holder.binding.simpleItemPile.background = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(
            context,
            itemBackground
        )
    }
```

All together, we have:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PileListeViewHolder, position: Int) {

    val pile = listePiles[position]
    holder.bind(pile)

    // I would move all the following logic into holder.bind() for consistency:
    holder.binding.simpleItemPile.setOnClickListener {
        onItemSelected(pile)
        val previouslySelectedItemPosition = position
        selectedItemPosition = position
        notifyItemChanged(position)
        if (previouslySelectedItemPosition != null) {
            notifyItemChanged(previouslySelectedItemPosition)
        }
    }
    val context = holder.binding.root.context
    val itemBackground = if (selectedItemPosition == holder.adapterPosition) R.drawable.background_bleu_statut else R.drawable.background_your_default_unselected_color
    holder.binding.simpleItemPile.background = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(
            context,
            itemBackground
        )
    }

}
```